# find all spaces, newlines and tabs in a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def count_spaces(filename): 
    input_file = open(filename,'r') 
    file_contents = input_file.read() 
    space = 0 
    tabs = 0 
    newline = 0 
    for line in file_contents == " ": 
        space +=1 
        return space
    for line in file_contents == '\t': 
        tabs += 1 
        return tabs 
    for line in file_contents == '\n': 
        newline += 1
        return newline 
    input_file.close()
```

I'm trying to write a function which takes a filename as a parameter and returns the total number of all spaces, newlines and also tab characters in the file. I want to try use a basic for loop and if statement but I'm struggling at the moment :/ any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What are you "struggling" with? Can you show your code and ask a specific question about it? If you're getting an exception, post the full traceback. We can't help you if you don't show us what's going wrong.

Comment: def count_num_of_spaces(filename): 
    input_file = open(filename,'r') 
    file_contents = input_file.read() 
    space = 0 
    tabs = 0 
    newline = 0 
    for line in file_contents == " ": 
        space +=1 
        return space
    for line in file_contents == '\t': 
        tabs += 1 
        return tabs 
    for line in file_contents == '\n': 
        newline += 1
        return newline 
    input_file.close()

Comment: how do i add code ?? I'm new here

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't work because you're combining loop syntax (`for x in y`) with a conditional  test (`x == y`) in a single muddled statement. You need to separate those.

You also need to use just a single `return` statement, as otherwise the first one you reach will stop the function from running and the other values will never be returned.

Try:

```
for character in file_contents:
    if character == " ":
        space +=1
    elif character == '\t': 
        tabs += 1
    elif character == '\n': 
        newline += 1
return space, tabs, newline
```

The code in Joran Beasley's answer is a more Pythonic approach to the problem. Rather than having separate conditions for each kind of character, you can use [the `collections.Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of all characters in the file, and just extract the counts of the whitespace characters at the end. A `Counter` works much like a dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_spaces(filename):
    with open(filename) as in_f:
        text = in_f.read()
    count = Counter(text)
    return count[" "], count["\t"], count["\n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To support large files, you could read a fixed number of bytes at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import namedtuple

Count = namedtuple('Count', 'nspaces ntabs nnewlines')

def count_spaces(filename, chunk_size=1 << 13):
    """Count number of spaces, tabs, and newlines in the file."""
    nspaces = ntabs = nnewlines = 0
    # assume ascii-based encoding and b'\n' newline
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        chunk = file.read(chunk_size)
        while chunk:
            nspaces   += chunk.count(b' ')
            ntabs     += chunk.count(b'\t')
            nnewlines += chunk.count(b'\n')
            chunk = file.read(chunk_size)
    return Count(nspaces, ntabs, nnewlines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count_spaces(__file__))
```

#### Output

```
Count(nspaces=150, ntabs=0, nnewlines=20)
```

---

[`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) allows you to treat a file as a bytestring without actually loading the whole file into memory e.g., you could search for a regex pattern in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mmap
import re
from collections import Counter, namedtuple

Count = namedtuple('Count', 'nspaces ntabs nnewlines')

def count_spaces(filename, chunk_size=1 << 13):
    """Count number of spaces, tabs, and newlines in the file."""
    nspaces = ntabs = nnewlines = 0
    # assume ascii-based encoding and b'\n' newline
    with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as file, \
         mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        c = Counter(m.group() for m in re.finditer(br'[ \t\n]', s))
        return Count(c[b' '], c[b'\t'], c[b'\n'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count_spaces(__file__))
```

#### Output

```
Count(nspaces=107, ntabs=0, nnewlines=18)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C=Counter(open(afile).read())
C[' ']
```

Comment: do i just write that or can i use it in a for loop or if statement ??

Comment: because ive never used the counter function yet thats why :P

Comment: Read the [Counter documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case tab(\t) is converted to "     "(four spaces). So i have modified the 
logic a bit to take care of that.

```
def count_spaces(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f1:
        contents=f1.readlines()

    total_tab=0
    total_space=0
    for line in contents:
        total_tab += line.count("    ")
        total_tab += line.count("\t")
        total_space += line.count(" ")
    print("Space count = ",total_space)
    print("Tab count = ",total_tab)
    print("New line count = ",len(contents))
    return total_space,total_tab,len(contents)
```